# How to bind components with vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have form and select components.
In fact things are simple: I need two binding model.

The parent component:

```
    Vue.component('some-form', {
      template: '#some-form',
      data: function() {
        return {
          countryNameParent: ''
        }
      }
   });
```

The child component with items:

```
Vue.component('countries', {
  template: '#countries',
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: {
        "0": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Afghanistan"          
        },
        "1": {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Afghanistan2"          
        },
        "2": {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Afghanistan3"          
        }
      },
      countryName: ''
    }
  },
  props: ['countryNameParent'],
  created: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.countryName = this.countryNameParent;
  },

  methods: {
    onChange: function (e) {
      this.countryNameParent = this.countryName;
    }
  }
});
```

I'm using `v-model` to incorporate components above.
Templates like this:

```
<template id="some-form">
  {{ countryNameParent }}
  <countries v-model="countryNameParent"></countries>
</template>

<template id="countries">
  <label for="">
    <select name="name" @change="onChange" v-model="countryName" id="">
      <option value="0">Select the country!</option>
      <option v-for="item in items" v-bind:value="item.name">{{ item.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</template>
```

My target is getting data in parent component to send it to server (real form is much bigger), however I can't get the value of the `countryName` in `countryNameParent`. Moreover, Parent should setting data in successor if not empty.

Here you go [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpOmZE) where I've been attempting to do it several ways (see commented part of it).
I know that I need to use `$emit` to set data correctly, I've even implemented model where I get image as base64 to send it by dint of the same form, hence I think solution is approaching!

Also: [reference](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvzwzO) where I've built sample with image.

Comment: You just need to implement `v-model` properly. Here is your [pen updated](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/OzLdpK?editors=1010).

Comment: I appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your `countries` component updated to support `v-model`.

```
Vue.component('countries', {
  template: `
  <label for="">
    <select v-model="countryName">
      <option value="0">Select the country!</option>
      <option v-for="item in items" v-bind:value="item.name">{{ item.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  `,
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: {
        "0": {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Afghanistan"          
        },
        "1": {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Afghanistan2"          
        },
        "2": {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Afghanistan3"          
        }
      },
    }
  },
  props: ['value'],
  computed:{
    countryName: {
      get() { return this.value },
      set(v) { this.$emit("input", v) }
    }
  },
});
```

`v-model` is just sugar for setting a `value` property and listening to the `input` event. So to support it in any component, the component needs to accept a `value` property, and emit an `input` event. Which property and event are used is configurable (documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model)).